# I am trying to place "user_input" inside a function, but i get the error "illegal start of an expression"

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

Keep getting the error 'illegal start of expression' when I try to make a function
thank you for the help in advance.

```
 import java.util.*;

public class project0
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            Random gen;
            gen = new Random();
            int x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, x4, y4, x5, y5;
            int cx1, cy1, cx2, cy2, cx3, cy3, cx4, cy4, cx5, cy5;
            int[] player = new int[10];
            int[] comp = new int [10];
            int shot_x, shot_y, compshot_x, compshot_y;
            int hits, comphits;

//RIGHT HERE IS THE FUNCTION
                user_input(scan, player);

            public static void user_input(Scanner scan, int[] player)
            System.out.println("Welcome to battleship, please enter x and y");
            System.out.println("coordinates for 5 ships within a 4x4 grid");
            x1 = scan.nextInt();
            player[0] = x1;
            y1 = scan.nextInt();
            player[1] = y1;
            x2 = scan.nextInt();
            player[2] = x2;
            y2 = scan.nextInt();
            player[3] = y2;
            x3 = scan.nextInt();
            player[4] = x3;
            y3 = scan.nextInt();
            player[5] = y3;
            x4 = scan.nextInt();
            player[6] = x4;
            y4 = scan.nextInt();
            player[7] = y4;
            x5 = scan.nextInt();
            player[8] = x5;
            y5 = scan.nextInt();
            player[9] = y5;

//Ignore everything below this line:        


                cx1 = Math.abs( gen.nextInt() ) % 4;
                comp[0] = cx1;
                cy1 = Math.abs( gen.nextInt() ) % 4;
                comp[1] = cy1;
                cx2 = Math.abs( gen.nextInt() ) % 4;
                comp[2] = cx2;
                cy2 = Math.abs( gen.nextInt() ) % 4;
                comp[3] = cy2;
                cx3 = Math.abs( gen.nextInt() ) % 4;
                comp[4] = cx3;
                cy3 = Math.abs( gen.nextInt() ) % 4;
                comp[5] = cy3;
                cx4 = Math.abs( gen.nextInt() ) % 4;
                comp[6] = cx4;
                cy4 = Math.abs( gen.nextInt() ) % 4;
                comp[7] = cy4;
                cx5 = Math.abs( gen.nextInt() ) % 4; 
                comp[8] = cx5;
                cy5 = Math.abs( gen.nextInt() ) % 4;
                comp[9] = cy5;


            hits = 0;
            comphits = 0;
            int i;
            for(i = 0; hits < 5 || comphits < 5; i++)
            {
                      System.out.println("Enter coords for your shot");
                      shot_x = scan.nextInt();
                      shot_y = scan.nextInt();

                      if(shot_x == comp[0] || shot_y == comp[1])
                      {
                              System.out.println("Nice hit!");
                              hits++;

                      }       
                      else if(shot_x == comp[2] || shot_y == comp[3])
                      {
                              System.out.println("Nice hit!");
                              hits++;
                      }       
                      else if(shot_x == comp[4] || shot_y == comp[5])
                      {
                              System.out.println("Nice hit!");
                              hits++;
                      }       
                      else if(shot_x == comp[6] || shot_y == comp[7])
                      {
                              System.out.println("Nice hit!");
                              hits++;
                      }       
                      else if(shot_x == comp[8] || shot_y == comp[9])
                      {
                              System.out.println("Nice hit!");
                              hits++;
                      }       
                      else
                               System.out.println("You missed");        

                      compshot_x = Math.abs( gen.nextInt() ) % 4;
                      compshot_y = Math.abs( gen.nextInt() ) % 4;

                           if(compshot_x == player[0] || compshot_y == player[1])
                      {
                              System.out.println("You were hit!");
                              comphits++;

                      }       
                      else if(compshot_x == player[2] || compshot_y == player[3])
                      {
                              System.out.println("You were hit!");
                              comphits++;
                      }       
                      else if(compshot_x == player[4] || compshot_y == player[5])
                      {
                              System.out.println("You were hit!");
                              comphits++;
                      }       
                      else if(compshot_x == player[6] || compshot_y == player[7])
                      {
                              System.out.println("You were hit!");
                              comphits++;
                      }       
                      else if(compshot_x == player[8] || compshot_y == player[9])
                      {
                              System.out.println("You were hit!");
                              comphits++;
                      }       
                      else
                               System.out.println("You are still safe");




            }


            if (comphits == 5)
                    System.out.println("You win! Congrats.");
            else
                    System.out.println("You lost to a machine! Loser.");





    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your post to fix the formatting, it is not clear as it is. If there is code that you think we can ignore, just remove it from your question.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot define a method within a method in java.

So, you cannot declare

```
public static void user_input(Scanner scan, int[] player)
```

in the middle of main.

Complete defining main ( end with a curly braces ) and then declare "user_input"

Answer (score 0):

You forgot a curly brace, also try to follow standard Java naming convention

```
public static void userInput(Scanner scan, int[] player) {
  System.out.println("Welcome to battleship, please enter x and y");
```

Comment: i put them there and i still get the error. i am very confused